# how to run jquery script on event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to run jquery script every select `changed`.

example i have `html` like this

```
<select name="typedata[]" data-long="long0" onchange="myFunction()">
     <option value="" label="default"></option>
     @foreach ($typeDatas as $typeData)
          <option value="{{ $typeData['nama'] }}">{{ $typeData['nama'] }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

and the script is like this

```
function myFunction(){
  console.log(jQuery(this).val())
}
```

jquery return error when i change the select.

is there a way to run jquery script inside `myFunction`, cause if im using javascript not jquery its work..

i cant use something like this `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`, because `select` was added when user click some `button` to add `select form`.

Comment: Select elements' change event can't be delegated, therefore the change handler must be attached after the select element has been created and appended to the DOM. The most obvious place to perform the attachment would be in the same code block as the append statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new select element doesn't have an event handler because it was created after the dom was rendered. However, you can use the "on" handler to bind an element regardless if it's rendered in the DOM or not. hope this helps.

https://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('html #formID').on("change","select", function(){
   // do something...
})
```

Also, You can remove the `onchange="myFunction()"`.  :)

Answer (score 1):

For the jQuery style you would do something like:

```
<select name="typedata[]" data-long="long0" class="class-name">
<option value="" label="default"></option>
 @foreach ($typeDatas as $typeData)
      <option value="{{ $typeData['nama'] }}">{{ $typeData['nama'] }}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

And then:

```
$('document').on('change', '.class-name', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

this binds the event `change` to the static and dybamic elements `.class-name` on the static parent element `document`.